# php cos not functioning?

Tags: php, math

I have a lat, in this case, `29` or `45`

I plot it in here

```
$lonchangepermile = cos($startlat) * 69.172;

var_dump($startlat);
var_dump('b');
var_dump($lonchangepermile);
```

and I get the results `-51.744` and `36.33` (see screenshot)

according to my brain, and my windows calculator it should be `48.911` and `60.499`

Whats the deal?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using degrees. PHP, like many other languages uses radians. Use `deg2rad()` on your inputs.

Comment: Actually PHP uses directly the C math lib (that uses radians)

Comment: yup... just came to that conclusion too... free answer points for you - time for bed for me... ty